# PHPickerViewController does not display photos (they seem to be transparent)

Tags: ios, swift

For some reason PHPickerViewController does not display the photos. They are there as i can select them but the cells seem to be transparent. Any idea what is causing this?

[image]

Comment: Are you using any `UIAppearance` methods in your app?

Comment: @EmilioPelaez might be used in pods but not directly no

Comment: @EmilioPelaez you where completely right ...someone added aperance and was causing the issue..thank you

Comment: Happy to help. I've added an answer that you can mark as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calls to `UIAppearance` can have an effect on external framework views, like `PHPickerViewController`.

I would suggest looking for calls to appearance methods that could be causing this, and modifying them so that they only affect the views in your application.